# Modify main loop to show posts after date user registered

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've been playing with this for a few days now and have had no success at all.

I want to modify index.php so the main loop only shows posts that were published after the logged in user registered on the site(content is already hidden for non-logged in users)

I can get the registered date, I can modify the loop so it shows posts after a certain date but cannot do both together.

Can anyone help me solve this please? here is the code I have so far -

```
    <?php $regdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered)); ?>

        <?php
        function filter_where($where = '') {
        $where .= " AND post_date >= '2016-02-18'";
        return $where;
        }
        add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
        query_posts($query_string);
        ?>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a code example I've tried but cannot get the $regdate into the functions and have no idea if I'm even on the right track so was open to any help...

Comment: still nowhere near enough of your code to even start to look at this one... where is `query_posts()` defined? `add_filter()`? as a wild guess, you're calculating `$regdate` so you need to pass this to your `filter_where` function, so it becomes `$where .= " AND post_date >= '".$regdate."'";` but that really is a stab in the dark

Comment: This code is directly above the main loop in index.php. I used $regdate to get the date the current user logged in. I want the posts to start on this date. So you're right I need to know how to get $reg date in place of '2016-02-18' in my function but you're example does not work either. There is no other code to see, everything I need is there just not combined... As I said, I don't even know if I'm on the right track which is why I'm asking if anyone has any idea how to achieve the second line in my question...

Comment: when I asked 'where', I meant, you haven't shown that code in your post, so we've no idea what it's doing. Without seeing the functions, we can't help too much - there definitely is other code to see. My example was only an aid - you'll need to pass $reg_date into your filter_where function somehow, but as we can't see how add_filter() works, it's hard to say how...

Comment: @RobGudgeon, it's been answered below. Turns out my code was on the wrong path as I suspected. Looking back maybe I didn't make it clear i was using Wordpress hence you didn't know what I was trying to do. Thanks for trying though, most appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, knowing it was wordpress may have helped :) I've never used it, wasn't aware of those functions. Glad it's sorted for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a candidate for WP Query, [which already has established parameters to query via date.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)

In the case you provided, your code would look something like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): ?>
<?php
# Get the current user's info
$user_info = get_userdata(get_current_user_id());
# Use date_parse to cast your date to an array 
$regdate = date_parse($user_info->user_registered);
# Set your arguments for WP Query        
$args = array(
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'after'    => array(
                # Setting date to array above allows to call specific values within that date    
                'year'  => $regdate['year'],
                'month' => $regdate['month'],
                'day'   => $regdate['day'],
            ),
            # Include posts from the day the user registered  
            'inclusive' => true,
        ),
    ),
    # Display all posts on a single page.
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<article class="post post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <h2 class="blog__custom-content-title"><?php the_title();?></h2>
    <?php the_content();?>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <h2>No posts to display</h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It's currently not working and Im still seeing all posts  of every date. When I echo $regdate[year] its says '1970' which is the default and not true of the logged in user, what could be going wrong?

Comment: Check out the edited version. Changed `getdate` to `date_parse` and tested it on a local WP install. Looks like it's working for me. Can you confirm?

Comment: YES! Cameron, you've cracked it. Thank you so much. I was way off with my original idea but this works perfectly and also gives me a lot of flexibility in what I add to the query. Thanks again!